# Which user-agent string can I use for web.whatsapp.com?

Tags: whatsapp, user-agent

I am using mobilefx browser based on Chromium.

I am using it to navigate to web.whatsapp.com.
It used to work fine.

Since today (June, 14th, 2022) this website doesn't work anymore and says that I need to use Safari, Google Chrome, Firefox or Opera.

The developer told me that this is nothing that he can fix.
Instead I need to set the user-agent myself.

The first thing I tried to find out was which version of whatsapp is causing this issue.
I inspected the source code of web.whatsapp.com, but I didn't find any version hint.

So I didn't know what to google.

So currently I have no idea which user-agent I need to return in order to make web.whatsapp.com think that all is good.

How could I go on?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just copy one from a browser on your local machine that you know works on the target URL? Even lower effort: why not just look up any one of the many sites that track the aforementioned vendors’ User Agent strings and try them one by one?

Comment: @esqew Could you tell me how to copy one from my browser? I did try try about 30 user-agent strings that I could find when googeling this issue, but none of them worked.

Comment: I have copied my own user-agent from all my browsers using https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/?analyse-my-user-agent=yes#parse-useragent. None of them worked. But thank you very much.

Comment: It worked after I changed the cookies. Do you want to make your comment the answer?

Comment: If my comment isn’t what worked, not sure why I would make it an answer. You should self-answer with a detailed explanation of what you changed along with the [mre] updated to reflect said changes.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by having a look at my own browser's user-agent settings.
To inspect my browser's user-agent settings, I visited [this website](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/?analyse-my-user-agent=yes#parse-useragent) and copied the results.

In my case, it was

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/73.0.3683.75 Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36
```

In the mobilefx browser, I set this user agent settings in the OnCreate sub:

```
 Private Sub webkit1_OnCreate(ByVal Settings As WebKitXCEF3Lib.ISettings, CommandLineSwitches As String)

     Settings.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/73.0.3683.75 Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36"

 End Sub
```

I also had to clear my browser's cookies.

Then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Useragent That is Supported by the Whatsapp web website today on Linux/Ubuntu - In my case is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36
```

and on Windows it Can Also be used

Comment: I tried yours. Still error the same.